# Itemize: Align terms

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize

Can I align several terms in an item-list?
See my code. x, y and z are not aligned... Could I use amsmath?

**My Code:**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item $x\qquad\,y\qquad\,z$
    \item $x\qquad\,y\qquad\,z$
    \item $x+2+3\qquad\,y\qquad\,z$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked,

> ... Could I use amsmath?

Short answer: Yes.

Slightly longer answer: Here's a solution that employs an `alignedat` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignedat' environment
\begin{document}

$\begin{alignedat}{3}
\bullet\quad & x     &\qquad& y &\qquad& z \\
\bullet\quad & x     &      & y &      & z \\
\bullet\quad & x+2+3 &      & y &      & z 
\end{alignedat}$

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The following code chunk shows how one might add an additional explicit alignment column, for the bullet symbols. (They're perfectly alignment in the screenshot shown above, but the OP appears to be applying some modifications to my code that makes the alignment of the bullet symbols fall apart.) Note that the output of the following code should be identical to what's shown in the earlier screenshot.

```
$\begin{alignedat}{4}
&\bullet &\quad & x     &\qquad & y &\qquad & z \\
&\bullet &\quad & x     &       & y &       & z \\
&\bullet &\quad & x+2+3 &       & y &       & z 
\end{alignedat}$
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I align the bullets without error message?

Comment: @Sylvia - I'm afraid my mind-reading skills are utterly worthless. Hence, do please reveal which error message(s) you get.  FWIW, I do *not* get any error or warning messages when I compile the example code on my system (MacOS, MacTeX2023, all updates installed).

Comment: @ Mico, sorry! If I add another & in front of all \bullet, I get: Package amsmath Error: Extra & on this line.

Comment: @Sylvia - Please explain why you added the extra `&` symbols. (There's a good reason why I did *not* place `&` symbols before the `\bullet` directives.)

Comment: Because I want to align the bullets as well (as in itemize). I should have said that - as usually, I did not know that

Comment: @Sylvia - Please see the addendum I posted to my answer.

Comment: many thanks! I forgot to change the number in \begin{alignedat}{}...
The alignment falls appart when I have longer code snippets

Answer (score 6):

You can use `eqparbox`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\begin{itemize}
\item \eqmakebox[A1][l]{$x$}\qquad\eqmakebox[B1][l]{$y$}\qquad\eqmakebox[C1][l]{$z$}
\item \eqmakebox[A1][l]{$x$}\qquad\eqmakebox[B1][l]{$y$}\qquad\eqmakebox[C1][l]{$z$}
\item \eqmakebox[A1][l]{$x+2+3$}\qquad\eqmakebox[B1][l]{$y$}\qquad\eqmakebox[C1][l]{$z$}
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2][1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first argument in brackets to `\eqmakebox` is a label that's shared by all boxes we want to have the same width. In this case I chose `A1`, `B1` and `C1`. For the next similar alignments use, say, `A2` and so on. The second argument in brackets is the inner alignment, in this case `l`eft.